# List of safe to remove applications

Tags: uninstall

I would like to ask if there is any list of pre-installed applications in Ubuntu which are safe to remove.

Once, I tried to uninstall unnecessary applications from **Software center**, but it created some bugs. For example, I lost some icons from **System settings**, and then I had to do `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` to recover lost data.

I would like to remove unnecessary applications, but I don't want to break my system.

Comment: Define "safe", servers for example do not need a graphical desktop, so Ubuntu runs fine without Unity ;). Remember if you break Ubuntu you get to keep both pieces. In general, if you have to ask, just stay with the defaults or if you prefer it is easier to start with a minimal install and build up then it is to remove things.

Comment: Safe for desktop i mean, for example firefox, empathy, bluetooth, program for listening etc.. I would like to start with minimal installation, but instalation doesnt support graphical installation :( only text-based

Comment: this post was 4 years ago, but it is still popular now a day. I would like to see the updated list for Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need to define what considers "break my system". A system without a desktop is not broken as is.

Besides that: the safest way is what you did and to take a look at this by "category" from Ubuntu Software Center and the "installed" group.

```
Accessories
Books & Magazines
Developer Tools
Education
Fonts
Games
Graphics
Internet
Medicine
Office
Science & Engineering
Sound & Video
Themes & Tweaks
Universal Access
```

Besides "accessories" any of these should be safe to remove and will not remove anything important since they all point to applications. Remove them 1 by 1 and do pay attention to the list of packages it is offering to delete just in case.

And when in doubt check the packages online for what is depending.

1 more comment: what you did was probably overkill; to get those icons back in system settings all you had to do is re-install that specific packages. This should have been enough to fix it:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

Comment: What about dependencies (installed as recommendations for packages). They aren't removed on package remove as i remember, and they're not displayed in software center sometimes. I always thought Ubuntu full of such packages..

Comment: That's how I removed python from my system: by looking at the developer tools and removing the stuff I wasn't interested in... (this was quite a few years ago though)  **:P ;-)**

Answer (score 11):

Ubuntu comes with a lot of GNOME applications pre-installed for giving the users an overall good desktop experience. Many of them have a deep system integration ... so it's not recommended to remove them - a good example is nautilus. But there are features that are quite safe to remove ... such as the controversially discussed online search integration that Canonical provides in Ubuntu.
As this is an aspect being more opinion based ... I give you a list of packages that I have removed :

```
account-plugin-aim  
account-plugin-facebook  
account-plugin-flickr  
account-plugin-jabber  
account-plugin-salut  
account-plugin-yahoo  
aisleriot  
gnome-mahjongg  
gnome-mines  
gnome-sudoku  
landscape-client-ui-install  
unity-lens-music  
unity-lens-photos  
unity-lens-video  
unity-scope-audacious  
unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks  
unity-scope-clementine  
unity-scope-colourlovers  
unity-scope-devhelp  
unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks  
unity-scope-gmusicbrowser  
unity-scope-gourmet  
unity-scope-guayadeque  
unity-scope-musicstores  
unity-scope-musique  
unity-scope-openclipart  
unity-scope-texdoc  
unity-scope-tomboy  
unity-scope-video-remote  
unity-scope-virtualbox  
unity-scope-zotero  
unity-webapps-common
```

Note :

Uninstalling **unity-webapps-common** removes the Amazon Search feature from the Unity desktop environment. In Ubuntu 15.10 I had to reinstall unity-webapps-service afterwards.
The reinstallation of the package unity-webapps-service wasn't necessary in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: `a good example is nautilus` I'd rather remove Nautilus and use file manager of my own choice =P